# Two events into one action

Tags: c#

In my Windows Phone App I try to combine two events into one action and would need some help, please.

When using the virtual keyboard, if you e.g. place your finger at the "Q" key, drag the finger to the "W" key and then release, you get the "W". This is what I try to replicate.

The DragCompleted event gives me "Q" as OriginalSource and the X/Y-distance the finger has moved. So I could calculate at which button the drag was completed. But I prefer ways without calculating to prevent rounding errors.

I found that the MouseLeave event of the "W" key is firing in the situation. So I think I just have to combine the DragCompleted event with the MouseLeave event to determine the key at which the finger was lifted.
Problem: I can't be sure (or I don't know) which event comes first. If DragCompleted waits for MouseLeave it will fail if MouseLeave came first. If MouseLeave waits for DragCompleted it will fail if DragCompleted came first.

Anyone have an idea to solve the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a flag when the events fire, and if the other one fires, check if corresponding flag is set.

But maybe there's actually a simpler solution. Why not just consider the key where the released event occurs in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If the user moves his finger fast along e.g. "QWERT...." and lift finger, it would produce many MouseLeave events. When working with flags it would not always get the right key, I think.
I guess I have to do the math way. But anyway thanks.